# How to find the interval between two dates with out using time

Tags: android, datetime

This is my code to calculate the interval between event date and current date using time. Here i am calculating interval based on the time. I don't want that. I want only the difference of days. I mean consider if event date is 25-09-2015 **current date:23-09-2015** Then interval will be 2 days. I need this type of code. Please help me to find out the code

```
String eventDate = btn_Date.getText().toString();
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
Date date1 = date.parse(eventDate);

Date currentDate = new Date();
daysBefore = (int) ((date1.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Comment: @sathyanagaraj19 try my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051535/how-to-display-the-already-while-adding-event-clicked-check-box-while-updating

Comment: Can you see my question..Help me to find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Here I format the currentDate too. This is skip the time, now you can get the exact remaining days.

```
 String eventDate = btn_Date.getText().toString();
 DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
    try {
        Date date1 = date.parse(eventDate);
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate = date.parse(date.format(currentDate));
        long difference = date1.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
        long diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(difference , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Log.i("remaining days", diff+ "");

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: just re-format the current date to (dd-M-yyyy) this will skipped the remaining time. so current date and event date is same format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714407/how-to-set-the-values-inside-the-check-box-on-click-box-listener-while-clicking

Comment: Can u please check this and tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the two `Date` objects you can make a small method that calculates it for you. Something like this:

```
public static long findDayDiff(Date date1, Date date2) {
    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(difference , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Did you call it with `findDayDiff(currentDate, date1)` ?

Comment: ya...i called that method

Comment: What should is be based on else? At some point you will have to get the `Time` of the `Date`s

Comment: I need to calculate the days...event date is 25-09-2015 current date is   23-09-2015....i need to get the interval as 2 days....If your calculating by time(i mean using get time),it will return interval as 1 days. Because by time already we passed half a day so it will return only 1 day...I dont want that...

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyTimeActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyTimeActivity";

    //Activity
    private Context mContext;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.mContext = this;

        Calendar cal1 = stringToCalendar("2012-03-20");
        Calendar cal2 = stringToCalendar("2012-03-26");
        String elapsedDaysText = getElapsedDaysText(cal1, cal2);
    }

    public static Calendar stringToCalendar(String dateString)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        try
        {
            date = sdf.parse(dateString);
            cal.setTime(date);
        }
        catch(ParseException e)
        {
            cal = null;
        }
        return cal;
    }   

    public String getElapsedDaysText(Calendar c1, Calendar c2)
    {
        long ms1 = c1.getTimeInMillis();
        long ms2 = c2.getTimeInMillis();
        long ps = (ms2 - ms1) / 1000;
        long elapsedDays = ps / 60 / 60 / 24;
        String elapsedDaysText = String.format("%d days ago", elapsedDays);
        return elapsedDaysText;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find this

```
  long days = 0;
  long seconds = 0;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            Date date1 = sdf.parse(firstDate);
            Date date2 = sdf.parse(nextDate);
            long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
            days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            seconds = days *24*60*60
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```